# Question on maximal of continuous function

Tags: real-analysis

Consider a continuous function $f(x):[0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb R$. Assume it attains maximum at 3 points. Can we say, then, that $f^3(x)-f^2(x)+5f(x)-14$ attains maximum at exactly 3 points?
In my opinion, it should be true, because we take the composition with good (continuous and differentiable) function $g(x) = x^3 - x^2+5x-14$, but I can't make rigorous proof

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: I don't think your reasoning quite works. For example if you take $f(x) = \operatorname{sin}(x)$ then $f^3(x) - f^2(x)$ attaints is maximum much more often even though $x^3 - x^2$ is 'good'.

Comment: Thank you for the example. But I can't use here any differentiability results, because I told nothing about differentiability of the function.

Comment: I just provided an answer using the chain rule - I am not sure how to do it without differentiation. I will think about it and change my answer if I figure it out. Nevermind - I assumed $f$ was differentiable in my solution so it was incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

We will first prove
$$x_1 > x_2 \Longrightarrow x_1^3 -5x_1-14 > x_2^3 -5x_2-14 $$

Which can easily be done by derivatives.
and thus

$$ f(x_1) > f(x_2) \Rightarrow g(f(x_1)) > g(f(x_2)) $$